# connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, digital-ocean, unicorn

I follow ruby on rails one app click deployment. Database done well, even I check rails console everything working fine

```
017/02/26 15:34:17 [error] 18564#0: *31 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 121.52.156.57, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock:/", host: "188.166.157.124"
2017/02/26 15:35:42 [error] 32360#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 119.155.34.115, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "188.166.157.124"
2017/02/26 15:42:38 [error] 6296#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 119.152.140.90, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "188.166.157.124"
```

uncorn.conf is

```
listen "unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock"
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails/company_startup"
pid "/var/run/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
```

nginx is

```
upstream app_server {
server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen   80;
root /home/rails/nehbor-webserver/public;
server_name _;
index index.htm index.html;
client_max_body_size 1M;
location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                try_files $uri @app;
        }

 location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [unicorn documentation](https://bogomips.org/unicorn/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-listen), I think you should remove the `unix` part from the `listen` method in the configuration and change it to `listen "/var/run/unicorn.sock"`.

```
listen 3000 # listen to port 3000 on all TCP interfaces
listen "127.0.0.1:3000"  # listen to port 3000 on the loopback interface
listen "/path/to/.unicorn.sock" # listen on the given Unix domain socket
listen "[::1]:3000" # listen to port 3000 on the IPv6 loopback interface
```

Comment: Check this https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html, it says to add unix

Answer (score 0):

In short nginx is trying to re-direct to your app but it can't. Outside of basic configuration thing and structure, I think the most common issue is related to:

- ports
- sockets
- and for me (using aws ec2), I was using a domain that was linked via a cname record on my dns registar. The ip changed which changed domain server name and my record wasn't updated. I just changed it from the cname record name to my new elastic domain name.